# Preventing water from freezing (-20 °C) in a vinyl container

Tags: water, temperature

What is a safe anti-freezing liquid to use to dilute water, to prevent it from freezing at -20°C, without damaging the vinyl container it's stored in?

This container is a heavy bag, for punching. So the purpose would be to be repeatedly hit with force.
The bag can hold a total of 55 liters of water (by specs).

Comment: There is missing the essential context information, what is the purpose of this water in the first place. As suitable freezers depend on that.

Comment: I was trying to find a better way to say it, but really "punching". It's a punching bag. Before marking this as off topic, I asked already on the martial art stackexchange about this, but what every person did to help was search in external websites if a certain compound would eat vinyl. This stackexchange got the best (objectively, the ethanol will do exactly what was asked) answer by far.

Comment: If vinyl means PVC, there is danger to become brittle at low temperatures (statically or under impact) AFAIK PVC becomes brittle below 0 °C.

Comment: If if is polyethylene (perhaps there is a label like [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recycling_codes) on the bag), than the addition of ethanol suggested and the cold should not be a reason to worry too much.  (I speculate, the small bags for the freezer are made of PE.)

Comment: Seems like propylene glycol would be much less expensive and safer than denatured ethanol. Even 60 US proof vodka, as per Maurice’s answer, would be fairly expensive.

Comment: @Buttonwood I couldn't find any of the label, so I have to go by what customer support said, which is indeed "vinyl". It's essentially a buoy though, so it must be the same material of the buoys used for boats.

Comment: @EdV how much propylene glycol? still 30%?

Comment: It is sold as relatively non-toxic anti-freeze, so either the label of the container, or a web search, should reveal the temperature versus concentration information. Maybe straight from the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mixture $30$% w/w ethanol + $70$% w/w water freezes at -$20$°C. It does not damage vinyl containers.

Comment: @EdV Would not even pass as a bourbon, either.